# Antdesign: Call a function when you click on a Modal button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have created a Modal with Antdesign and want to call a function which logs the user out when he confirms the logout on the Modal pop up.
When I look at the API of Antdesign it shows that I have to use the property onOK and then call the function.
This is my code for the Modal:

```
import { logout } from '../../store/actions/auth';

function confirm({ logout }) {
  Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm your Logout',
    centered: true,
    okText: 'Logout',
    icon: <LogoutOutlined />,
    cancelButtonProps: {
      danger: true,
    },
    content: (
      <div>
      </div>
    ),
    onOk() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(Math.random() > 0.5 ? resolve : reject, 1000);
          }).catch(() => console.log('Modal errors!'));
    },
  });
}
```

I call the Modal with the onClick event on a div

```
<div onClick={confirm}>
```

Right now the onOk property just displays a loading spinner for one second but I also want to call the function logout which I have previously imported.
How can I also call the function before the loading spinner gets activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write it like

```
function confirm({ logout }) {
  Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm your Logout',
    centered: true,
    okText: 'Logout',
    icon: <LogoutOutlined />,
    cancelButtonProps: {
      danger: true,
    },
    content: (
      <div>
      </div>
    ),
    onOk: () => {
      // your logout function i.e this.props.logout()
    },
  });
}
```

I have got the reference from [here](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/antd/confirm)

Comment: Would be nice if you add an explanation from the code you post, aside from the reference you added nicely already :) Thanks!

Comment: @JonasLevin dont forget to upvote the answer if it's worked!!